# How to catch java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused on akka steram?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream, alpakka

I have a kafka consumer that looks as the following:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.kafka.scaladsl.Consumer
import akka.kafka.{ConsumerSettings, Subscriptions}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    implicit val system = ActorSystem("SAP-SENDER")
    implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
    implicit val materilizer = ActorMaterializer()

    val config = system.settings.config.getConfig("akka.kafka.consumer")

    val consumerSettings: ConsumerSettings[String, String] =
      ConsumerSettings(config, new StringDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
        .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9003")
        .withGroupId("SAPSENDER")
        .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")

    Consumer
      .plainSource(
        consumerSettings,
        Subscriptions.topics("TEST-TOPIC")
      )
      .runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
      .onComplete{
        case Success(_) => println("Goood")
        case Failure(ex) =>
          println(s"I am failed ==============> ${ex.getMessage}")
          system.terminate()
      }

  }
}
```

The kafka server is not active and I would like just to terminate the consumer. It always tries to connect and shows the following messages:

```
19:03:47.342 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-15] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] Pausing partitions []
19:03:47.342 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-15] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] No broker available to send FindCoordinator request
19:03:47.342 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-15] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
19:03:47.342 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-15] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] Coordinator discovery failed, refreshing metadata
19:03:47.342 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-15] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
19:03:47.412 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-17] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] Pausing partitions []
19:03:47.412 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-17] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] No broker available to send FindCoordinator request
19:03:47.412 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-17] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
19:03:47.412 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-17] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] Coordinator discovery failed, refreshing metadata
19:03:47.412 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-17] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
19:03:47.478 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-20] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAPSENDER] Pausing partitions []
```

it also says:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:515)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:467)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:535)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:231)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1214)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1179)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1164)
    at akka.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.poll(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:380)
    at akka.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.akka$kafka$internal$KafkaConsumerActor$$receivePoll(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:360)
    at akka.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:221)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.akka$actor$Timers$$super$aroundReceive(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.Timers.aroundReceive(Timers.scala:51)
    at akka.actor.Timers.aroundReceive$(Timers.scala:40)
    at akka.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.aroundReceive(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:610)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:579)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How to catch up the `ConnectException` in the stream and stop consumer from trying to connect kafka.

The code is hosted here https://gitlab.com/akka-samples/kafkaconsumer.

Answer (score 2):

With the Kafka Client 2.0+ Alpakka Kafka can't notice that there is no Kafka broker available on the given addresses.

See https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/issues/674

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this [PR](https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/pull/614) and the work to upgrade to kafka client 2.0 I'd guess a lot of retry responsibility has been delegated to the kafka client. For instance I tried passing these properties

```
val consumerSettings: ConsumerSettings[String, String] =
  ConsumerSettings(config, new StringDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
    .withProperties(
      "reconnect.backoff.ms" -> "10000",
      "reconnect.backoff.max.ms" -> "20000"
    )
    .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9099")
    .withGroupId("SAPSENDER")
    .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
```

And the exception appears the second time after 10 seconds. I found these properties [here](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#consumerapi)

Given that, I think there may be a missing feature with the new adaptation of the kafka client as the KafkaConsumerActor does not expose the exception to the stream, I tried various combinations using your repo but I still get a continuous stream of debug messages.

I hope this gives some hint to the right direction, please let us know if you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should monitor your stream and restart it if there are errors. For example you could run your stream inside an actor and handle error connections with actor supervision.

Connections errors are probably going to last during a couple of seconds (maybe the network is overwhelmed) so you should use a back-off strategy to avoid retries storm.

Akka stream already gives you a simple way of doing this for streams using `RestartSource`. See [Error Handling](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/errorhandling.html#restarting-the-stream-with-a-backoff-stage)

```
val control = new AtomicReference[Consumer.Control](Consumer.NoopControl)

val result = RestartSource
  .onFailuresWithBackoff(
    minBackoff = 3.seconds,
    maxBackoff = 30.seconds,
    randomFactor = 0.2
  ) { () =>
    Consumer
      .plainSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topic))
      // this is a hack to get access to the Consumer.Control
      // instances of the latest Kafka Consumer source
      .mapMaterializedValue(c => control.set(c))
      .via(businessFlow)
  }
  .runWith(Sink.seq)

control.get().shutdown()
```

This solution will only work when you start the stream and the broker is down because then the consumer throws an exception when you try to create it.
However, if you succeed creating your consumer and after that the whole kafka cluster crashes the internal KafkaConsumer will use the mentioned `reconnect.backoff.ms` and `reconnect.backoff.max.ms` configuration to reconnect and your stream will not fail.

If you want to limit the number of retires you should do the following

```
val result: Future[Done] = RestartSource
  .onFailuresWithBackoff(
    minBackoff = 3.seconds,
    maxBackoff = 30.seconds,
    randomFactor = 0.2
  ) { () => // your consumer  
  }.
  .take(3) // retries limit
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)

result.onComplete {
  case _ => println("Max retries reached")
}
```

Comment: The code, that you have shown above, where should I call `control.get().shutdown()`. After max. 4 retries, I would like to call `control.get().shutdown()` but where should I call it?

Comment: Is there any possibility to pass a callback to `RestartSource`, when the number of retries has been used?

Comment: I've cretead https://gist.github.com/bifunctor/55440b7515c479f15ddbf8ebd1656e85 and it does not stop properly. The kafka server is not active.